# sh: flake8: not found

Tags: docker-compose, flake8

I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days now. I am trying to dockerize a django REST API + react (create-react-app) application.

[problem: $ docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"
sh: flake8: not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpfWv.png)

I am trying to configure flake8 in gitbash using the code $ docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"

But there is a problem and it says:-

sh: flake8: not found

I tried running- `docker-compose build`  but the same problem still persists, please tell how to solve it?

Comment: your docker image does not have flake8 in it

Answer (score -1):

Use `$ which flake8` to understand how
your python virt env is supplying that dependency.

Adjust the PATH env var, perhaps via `$ conda activate myproject`
or `$ poetry run flake8`,
to let the dockerized container access that dependency.